# Scraping- Acceso a datos economicos en Investing

Tags: scraping

Mediante un codigo VBA en Excel que he encontrado por internet, he conseguido descargar los datos historicos deL activo de la pagina "https://es.investing.com/indices/stoxx-600-banks-pr-historical-data", pero no he sabido acceder al selector del Periodo ni tampoco al selector de fechas, por lo que la descarga que puedo realizar siempre es entre las fechas y periodo que se indica en la pagina. Les agradeceria me ayudaran a resolver mi cuestión con el codigo necesario para poder acceder a los controles idicados.
Les quedo agradecido de antemano por su ayuda.
Jose Miguel.

Comment: Sos el mismo usuario que hizo la edicion? si es asi, debemos fusionar tus cuentas. Si no, avisame, elimino esta publicacion, y hacemos una nueva. Eso es importante, porque debes poder aceptar la respuesta, y si perdiste acceso a la cuenta no vas a poder...